# Не понимаю почему в VS Code не работает gcc

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcc

Я давно столкнулся с проблемой ,что в visual studio не могу сделать , чтобы кол-во элементов массива определял пользователь , не используя динамические массивы . Мне объяснили почему это работает на Linux в KDevelop , потому что там есть gcc . Сейчас я установил MinGW с gcc , vs code и настроил его . Но проблема не исчезла

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)

{
    int n;
    int i;
    int b;

    printf("Введите кол-во элементов массива:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    float arr[n];
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Введите %d элемент массива\n ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &arr[i]);
    }

    printf("%f", arr[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Опишите конкретно, что за проблема. Если ошибка компиляции, то покажите ее.

Comment: Там ошибка в том , что кол-во элементов массива должно быть константой

Comment: Покажите ошибку дословно. Еще там где-то должна быть команда, которой вы компилируете.

Comment: У меня подчёркивается n, где размер массива и если навестись пишет : Выражение должно иметь константное значение C/C++(28)

Comment: Это сообщения самого VSC, а не компилятора. Попробуйте именно скомпилировать.